# How can I truncate .m4v elementary stream files?

Tags: windows, video-editing, mpeg4

I have two .m4v MPEG4-Visual elementary streams which need to be truncated down to a specific length, leaving the same starting point and simply specifying a frame number at which to end.

I have searched in all the places I know to try and find a tool to do this, but so far have been unsuccessful. I have even tried a couple of tools, but they were unable to open the files, presumably because they are elementary streams.

If it becomes absolutely necessary, I will probably be able to do it by hand using a Hex Editor, but a tool would make things so much quicker and easier.

Comment: What operating system do you use?

Comment: Oh, Sorry. Windows.

Comment: Does the stream have VOL headers or is it really just the data? Please also explicitly list all the tools you've tried to open the files with, and how exactly they failed.

Comment: I have just found that we have an internal Unix tool to do this. Problem sorted. Sorry.